# Open a file fails when nonblocking UDP port is open

Tags: c, sockets, file-io, udp, posix

I have a problem with a program. The program should be triggered by UDP messages, that's why I open a nonblocking UDP socket, because I want to use it later again. After that the program should open a file, copy out a certain amount of bytes and send it to a browser.

The problem occurs when I want to open a file, then I get a "resource temporarily not availabe" fault.

Here is a simple program, which creates the same fault.

main part:

```
udp_openPort(9999);

for(;;){
    if(udp_receiveData(temp, 32) > 0){
        printf("Received Message: %d\n",atoi(temp));
    break;
    }
} 

filefd = open("test.txt",O_RDONLY);
printf("File Open: %s\n",strerror(errno));

read(filefd,buff,sizeof(buff));

printf("Daten: %s",buff);

close(filefd);

udp_closePort();
```

udp_receiveData():

```
int udp_receiveData(void* data, int size){
    socklen_t dummy = sizeof(NetworkAddr);
    NetworkAddr sender;
    return recvfrom(sockfd, data, size, MSG_DONTWAIT, (struct sockaddr*) (&sender), &dummy);
}
```

When I open the socket as a blocking socket, there is no problem with opening the file, but I need I nonblocking socket for my purpose.

Did I make a mistake in coding the program or did I made a mistake, when I planned the program?

Best regards,
PG

EDIT: Here is the udp_openPort() function:

```
int udp_openPort(int portNr){

//Create handle to socket
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sockfd == -1){
    return 0;
}

// Make sure that we don't receive our own packets.
char loop = 0;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, &loop, sizeof(loop)) == -1){

}


// Bind to the port where we receive UDP messages.
NetworkAddr addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port        = htons(portNr);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1){
    return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

Maybe someone sees a problem in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the manpage of `open`, the `errno` is set if and only if the error occurred, i.e. when returned descriptor is `-1`. Hence, your error handling is incorrect. You should have checked the value of `filefd` in order to determine if the file has been opened or not.

Because the file in fact was opened correctly, `errno` hasn't been modified and your error message was set by `udp_receiveData`; in this case, as your socket is non-blocking, there was no data on UDP socket (*resource temporarily unavailable*). You don't experience this with a blocking socket, as your program is then sleeping waiting for a message to arrive.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. When I removed the errno-stuff and did the error handling with the returned descriptors everything worked fine. Now I know why, big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you `error` after `open` is not interfere with `udp_openPort`? Probably `udp_openPort` does something wrong and set the `errno` variable which you lately misinterpret as file open error.

Comment: I edited my post and added the udp_openPort() function. 
The udp_openPort function does not do anything with the errno variable. If the mistake would be there the problem would probably occur when I use a blocking socket as well.